# how to use interface and purpose of casting?

Tags: c#

i have used interface in both cases. is it my first case use interface ??
here is the my interface and class

```
interface IAddition {
    int Add();
}

interface IMultiplication {
    int Multiplication();
}
```

it is my class

```
public class Calculation : IAddition, IMultiplication {
    int x, y;
    public Calculation(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int Add() {
        return (x + y);
    }
    public int Multiplication() {
        return (x * y);
    }
}
```

1st case is this

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Calculation cal = new Calculation(20, 30);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is= " + cal.Add());
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication is= " + cal.Multiplication());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And 2nd case is this

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Calculation cal = new Calculation(20, 30);
        IAddition add = (IAddition)cal;
        IMultiplication mul = (IMultiplication)cal;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is= " + add.Add());
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication is= " + mul.Multiplication());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of these 2 lines ??? here what is the purpose of casting ?? Although 1st case have same output

```
IAddition add = (IAddition)cal;
IMultiplication mul = (IMultiplication)cal;
```

Comment: This example is too simple to illustrate why interfaces are useful; I suggest reading something like this: http://www.hitthebits.com/2012/11/why-use-interfaces.html

Answer (score 2):

Only the second case programs to `IAddition` and `IMultiplication` interfaces. The first case would work even if the `Calculation` class did not implement `IAddition` and `IMultiplication`.

> what is the purpose of casting?

Note that since you declare variables with an explicit interface type, you can safely drop the casts in the declarations of `mul` and `add`:

```
IAddition add = cal;
IMultiplication mul = cal;
```

You could also rewrite your declarations with implicit type declaration:

```
var add = (IAddition)cal;
var mul = (IMultiplication)cal;
```

> What is the purpose of these 2 lines?

These lines declare two variables using the interface type implemented by `Calculation`. They make no practical difference in this example, but generally you could use `add` and `mul` to be specific about the level of abstraction to which you program. For example, `IAddition add` tells the readers of your program that you do not need to use any aspects of `cal` except these related to addition.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `var add = (IAddition) cal;`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers cover the given example code, but it's worthwhile to add that the rules are different for *explicit* interface implementation.

For example, if the example class was implemented as follows:

```
public class Calculation : IAddition, IMultiplication {
    int x, y;
    public Calculation(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int IAddition.Add() {
        return (x + y);
    }
    public int IMultiplication.Multiplication() {
        return (x * y);
    }
}
```

then the cast *is* required. For example:

```
Calculation cal = new Calculation(10, 10);
cal.Multiplication(); // this will cause a compiler error
((IMultiplication)cal).Multiplication(); // This is the required way to do it
```

For more information [see this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the purpose is just to show you how you can cast types. It doesn't make a difference in how the code works, but you can see that if you were to try `add.Multiplication()`, the compiler would tell you that's not allowed.

In a simple example like this, there's no reason to cast and declare variables like this. However, in larger applications, the *Interface Segregation Principle* helps us to avoid tight coupling of different pieces of code. For example, you could write a method like this:

```
int SumAll(IAddition adder, params int[] values)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(int n in values)
    {
        sum = adder.Add(sum, values[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The above method would work just fine if you pass it a `Calculator`, but it doesn't *have to* use a `Calculator`. Since you know you don't need to multiply anything in this method, this limits your dependencies to the things that you actually need. You might in the future find it useful to implement an `Add` method with a ceiling, for example, that never allows numbers to go above a certain number, no matter how many things get added. Passing that `IAddition` object into `SumAll` would have a different effect, and you wouldn't have to create a different `SumAll` method to accommodate this need.

```
Console.WriteLine(SumAll(new Calculator(), 1, 2)); // 3
Console.WriteLine(SumAll(new Calculator(), 1, 2, 3)); // 6
Console.WriteLine(SumAll(new AdderWithMax(4), 1, 2)); // 3
Console.WriteLine(SumAll(new AdderWithMax(4), 1, 2, 3)); // 4
```

In general, people find that by separating interfaces intelligently, they're able to write code that's easier to test and less likely to require as much work when changes are made in the future--in other words, more maintainable code.

Oh, and by the way, the explicit cast isn't actually necessary, so this would also have the same effect:

```
IAddition add = cal;
```

or:

```
var add = (IAddition)cal;
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to use interface

There are many *ways* to use an inteface, from implementation to type-checking.

```
// Definition of interface or sometimes referred to as "Contract"
// Implementing classes must define these methods and properties
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void MyMethod();
  int MyProperty { get; }
}


// Implementation or sometimes referred to as "Concrete type"
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  public void MyMethod();
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

// Compile time type checking:
public void MyMethod<T>(T value)
  where T : IMyInterface
{ }

// Runtime checking
public void MyMethod(object someobject)
{
  var myinterface = someobject as IMyInterface;
  if (myinterface != null)
  {
    //someobject implements IMyInterface so I can do things with it
    someobject.MyMethod();
  }
}
```

> and purpose of casting?

The purpose of casting is has many uses.  I'll mostly be demonstrating use the `as` keyword because it provides type-safety for the run-time.

You can use it to validate a type implements an interface at run-time:

```
public MyMethod(object obj)
{
  var calc = obj as ICalc;
  if (calc != null)
  {
    calc.Calculate();
  }
}
```

This can be improved:

```
public void MyMethod(ICalc calc)
{
  calc.Calculate();
}
```

Using generics and compile time type safety (I think it's important to show).

```
public void MyMethod<TObject>(TObject calc)
  where TObject : ICalc
{
  calc.Calculate();
}
```

> is it my first case use interface ??

I'm not sure what this means, I think what you are trying to say is

> Am I required to use the interface by casting it?

No you are not.  Lets take a look at these two classes:

```
public class Calculation1 : IAddition, IMultiplication {
  public int Add() { //... ignoring implemenetation
  }

  public int Multiplication() { //... ignoring implemenetation
  }
} 

public class Calculation2 {
  public int Add() {//... ignoring implemenetation
  }

  public int Multiplication() {//... ignoring implemenetation
  }
}
```

Both of the classes implement the same methods so these are valid:

```
var one = new Calculation1();
one.Add();
var two = new Calculation1();
two.Add();
```

However because the first one implements an interface and the second one does not, you can pass the first object to methods that do not need to know the *concrete* type.

```
public void MethodNeedsToAdd(IAddition addCalculator)
{
  if (addCalculator != null)
  {
    addCalculator.Add();
  }
}

MethodNeedsToAdd(one);   // Valid
MethodNeedsToAdd(two);   // Invalid
```

Even though you and I can clearly see they both can "Add"  the second class `two` does not implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about concealing complexity.  When you do this cast ...

```
     IAddition add = (IAddition)cal;
```

You can then handle this `add` item as if all it can do is implement your `IAddition` interface. That might prove convenient if you were implementing a complex system.

For example, you might define an `IGetNextItem` interface. Then, you might choose to implement that interface in a class which fetched an item from a DBMS, and another which generated a random fake item.  You would be able to cast either object, and then pass it to some software which consumed those items, without needing to tell the consuming software exactly how the fetching of items actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the cast. You can say...

```
IAddition add = cal;
```

However, the point of that is you are creating an object of **any type that implements the IAddition interface**.